Connection with Snowflake Database using C#
public static DataTable ExecuteSnowflakeQuery(string query)
{

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Account=<>;user=<>;Password =<>;Role=ACCOUNTADMIN;db=<>;schema=public";
           conn.Open();
            using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "USE WAREHOUSE Warehousename";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var result = new DataTable();
                    result.Load(reader);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DbException exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Snowflake error: {exc.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

I'm unable connect to the snowflake database
Snowflake error:

Error: Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors
occurred. (A task was canceled.) SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 270001,
QueryId: An error occurred: Error: Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to
connect. One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.) SqlState:
08006, VendorCode: 270001, QueryId:    at
Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.SessionPool.NewSession(String
connectionString, SecureString password, SessionCreationToken
sessionCreationToken)    at
Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.SessionPool.GetSession(String connStr,
SecureString password)    at
Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.SessionPool.GetSession()    at
Snowflake.Data.Core.Session.ConnectionPoolManager.GetSession(String
connectionString, SecureString password)    at
Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnectionPool.GetSession(String
connectionString, SecureString password)    at
Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open()    at
Program.ExecuteSnowflakeQuery(String query) in
C:\Users\Poshaboina.Mahender\source\repos\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 69
at Program.Main(String[] args) in
C:\Users\Poshaboina.Mahender\source\repos\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 23

How can i fix this?

Please review the details for connecting to Snowflake from C# here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-C-Sharp-application-with-snowflake-NET-Connector-to-perform-SQL-operations-in-windows
Most likely some dependency is causing the issue.
